# Скачать файл через ssh2 соединения

Tags: php, ssh

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('***', 22);
sh2_auth_password($conn_id, 'root', '****');
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
if (!$connection) exit("Ошибка подключения");


// Закрытие соединение
ssh2_disconnect($connection);
```

Ошибки не выдает, зачет соединение успешно установлено.

Вопрос в том, как узнать в какой директории нахожусь после подключения.

Как скачать файл с удаленного сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При подключении к ssh пользователь попадает в свою домашнюю директорию.
В целом функции `ssh2_sftp_*` предназначены для работы с файловой системой, но узнать текущую дерикторию возможно.

```php
$connection = ssh2_connect('100.100.1.10', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'someuser', 'somepass');
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$realpath = ssh2_sftp_realpath($sftp, '.');
echo $realpath; // /home/someuser
```

Comment: Не знаю, ошибки в подключении не выдает. Но и на экран ничего не отдает, когда выводит путь, в чем может быть дело? Как скачать файл, скопировать на сервер?

Comment: если приведённый выше код не работает и ни чего не выдаёт, проблема может быть в отключенном error_reporting

Comment: display_errors/error_reporting включены. Хотелось бы понять в чем дело, в крайнем случаи сделаю на пайтоне

Comment: Все дело в том, что код был в try {, по логам увидел. Было отключено ssh